# fputcsv как сделать табы?

Tags: php, excel, csv

Есть массив `$arr` с текстовыми объектами по типу: `"target:value"`

Пытаюсь его перебрать таким способом, и записать значения в файл:

```
$fp = fopen($path.'.csv', 'a');

foreach ($all as $fields) {
    $fields = explode(':', $fields);
    fputcsv($fp, $fields, "\t");
}
fclose($fp);
```

Но проблема в том что мне нужно чтобы `target` был во первой ячейке таблицы, а `value` во второй.
Сейчас он все пишет в одну ячейку. Как можно добиться того чтобы он разбил по табам, `value` и `target`?

Comment: стандартный разделитель в csv это запятая. Если вы используете другой разделитель, как здесь, то и при дальнейшем просмотре документа надо использовать его.

Comment: @teran , да какой бы я разделитель не писал, он все равно в одну строку пишет

Comment: вопрос в том, как вы просматриваете получившийся документ. код с виду корректный, и элементу массива `t1:v1` будет соответствовать строка `t1\v1\n`  в файле.

Comment: @teran да просто в exel открываю и все ) без всяких настроек

Comment: открывайте через `файл-открыть`, тогда эксель запустит мастер импорта, где укажите используемый разделитель. а так да, он что-то не хочет автоматом разделять на столбцы. хз почему

Comment: разделяйте через точку с запятой, откроет

Answer (score 0):

При открытии `csv` файла средствами MS Excel используется разделитель значений, заданный в системе как *"Разделитель элементов списка"*, по умолчанию для русского языка используется точка с запятой`;`, т.к. стандартный разделитель `CSV`-формата (Comma separated values), запятая, используется для разделения дробной и целой части чисел.

Настройка разделителя находится в `Панель управления` - `Часы, язык и регион` - `Региональные стандарты` - `Изменение форматов даты, времени и чисел` - `Вкладка Форматы` - `Дополнительные параметры` - `Разделитель элементов списка` (win10).

Для систем Windows 7+ (а мб и более ранних) предпоследнее окно в этой цепочке можно открыть выполнив команду `control intl.cpl` (либо `control international`) через `Пуск-Выполнить`.

Поэтому, когда ваш csv документ сформирован с испоьзованием системного разделителя, Excel благополучно его откроет. В противном случае придется использовать мастер импорта текста.