# php fputcsv разбивка по столбцам

Tags: php, csv

Добрый день, 
Выгружаю csv через функцию fputcsv, при открытии в excel все данные в 1 столбце, разделитель ',' хочу разбить на столбцы и не нашел ответ на php.net, скажите как сделать, кто знает. спасибо. тестовый пример:

```
$a = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]
];
$file = fopen('test.csv', 'w');
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    fputcsv($file, $value);
}
```

Comment: 3 параметр разделитель указывает, пробовали его менять на ; к примеру?

Comment: [разделитель столбцов смотрите в настройках языковых стандартов в винде](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/688255/223826)

Comment: возможный дубликат вопроса [fputcsv как сделать табы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/688229/223826)

Comment: если кратко, то скорее всего использовать надо `;` а не запятую, т.к. последняя используется для разделения целой и дробной части.